# How to select last inserted row by id?

Tags: database, lastinsertid

that my problem:

I have database table like that:

```
id (AI)    market_id
1             6       
2            10      
3             6       
4            10   
5            11
```

How to select last inserted market_id by id?

Comment: please specify database and if the ID is of type AutoIncrement

Comment: Which one is the last inserted marked_id? 6, 10 or 11? How do you identify the "last"?

Comment: The last inserted marked_id I identify by id which is auto-increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <your_table> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you only are interested in the `market_id` you could change the `*` in the above query to `market_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID():

`SELECT market_id FROM <table> where id=LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server,

```
Select TOP 1 ID, market_I'd from table order by ID desc
```